# Always need to source ~/.bash_profile after system restart for ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable

Tags: android, bash, macos, react-native, environment-variables

I've had a look online and haven't found a resolution for this issue on Mac.

I am using react native and anytime I run `react-native run-android` in my terminal I get the following error

```
BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/aaronmccloskey/git/airbnb/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

The thing is, is that in my `.bash_profile` this environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` exists

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

When I run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it returns blank?

However, when I open the `.bash_profile` file and run `source ~/.bash_profile` and then run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it then returns the correct directory and running `react-native run-android` also works.

But why do I have to keep running `source ~/.bash_profile` every time I start up my system. It's a little frustrating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That shouldn’t happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: post a screenshot of a newly opened terminal